# displaying multi line rich text box in poi excel

Tags: apache-poi

I am using poi3.5 api to create excel report. Now I need a mutiline rich text box on excel sheet. I am not able to find the exact solution.Please guide me on this, if anyone has solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html
you may find the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a textbox with anchor and you are good to go. Following code will create textbox with 20px text, no border.

```
        HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        HSSFTextbox textbox1 = patriarch.createTextbox(new HSSFClientAnchor(0,0,1023,255,(short)4,2,(short)6,3));;
        HSSFRichTextString rt1 = new HSSFRichTextString("This is title");
        HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight((short)400);
        rt1.applyFont(font);
        textbox1.setString(rt1);
        textbox1.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE);
```

One thing to note is that coordinates in client anchor has limits and those limits are 1023 and 255. If you are not changing coordinates, textbox will reside between row1,row2 and col1,col2.